# How do i make this transform in lisp?

Tags: list

I need to make a function that transforms 2 list in one in lisp?Can you please help me?

(A B C) (X Y Z) --> ((A.X) (B.Y) (C.Z))

This is the example

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I tryed with acons function, but i get nowhere

Answer (score 0):

For the case you asked :

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'cons '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C))
```

If you want to generalize :

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'list '(1 2 3) '(a b c) '(x y z))
((1 A X) (2 B Y) (3 C Z))
```

In a function :

```
(defun foo (&rest l) 
    (apply #'mapcar #'list l))
```

Which gives:

```
CL-USER> (foo '(1 2 3) '(a b c) '(x y z))
((1 A X) (2 B Y) (3 C Z))
```